# Finding an array of possibilities from a set of given objects

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of 8 objects (a-h), and each object has a flag which can be set to 1 or 0.  Is there a method that can show all possible combinations of objects and their flag statuses?

For example:

- a=1,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0
- a=1,b=1,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0
- a=0,b=1,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0

etc..

If there is such a method, I'd deeply appreciate any help.  Please forgive me for my lack of math terminology!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count from $0$ to $255=2^8-1$ in binary, each number is eight bits.  If you consider the first bit a, the second bit b, etc., you are there.

Comment: Thank you Ross, thats exactly what I was looking for :)